# How to split integer (Occurrence of Integer from user Input)

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a program that counts the number of occurrence of integers from user input 
e.g. 121221315

0: 0 times

1: 4 times

2: 3 times

3: 1 times

4: 0 times... etc up until 9...

But my code reads e.g. 121221315 as a single integer and i need to find a way that can split each integers

Another issue is that I don't know how to stop the first for loop... I have no clue which condition to put in on how to stop the loop when the program finished reading the input... I have just started learning coding.. please help me with simple/easy codes!!

I have following code

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Occurrence {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
           

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] number = new int[100];

        System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            int a = input.nextInt();
            number[a] += a;
              break;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < number.length; i++) {
            if (number[i] != 0) {
                if (number[i] / i > 1)
                    System.out.println(i + " occurs " + number[i] / i + " times");
                else
                    System.out.println(i + " occurs " + number[i] / i + " time");               }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats about the javascript java thing? Thats not javascript. It's java!

Answer (score 1):

If you are given and `Integer`, you can convert it to a `String`, split it in an array of Strings, and using `stream` with `groupingBy` make a map of occurrences.

```
 Integer a = 121221315;

 Map<String, Long> collect = Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(a).split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

That's of course if you are allowed to use java 8 features.

The map will contain occurrences of digits that exist at least once. Logically the rest of digits have `0` occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! what if the user is to input the numbers? through keyboard

Comment: @SongPak, what do you mean ? This example is for numbers, ``String.valueOf(a)`` converts it to a string

Comment: like i wouldnt know the numbers given... i wouldnt know if the number will be 121221315... it could be somethingelse depending on the user input... maybe a = keyboard.nextInt(); ?